# How to mark something as a tag within a question body?

Tags: support, tags, markdown

I recently noticed that some people have been marking tags with specific markup on meta sites, such as the following example:

[Clarifying tags election, voting, and president](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2614/clarifying-tags-election-voting-and-president)

where, in: "Considering the raising interest towards ongoing presidential elections in the USA, I'd like to clarify using election, voting, and probably president and voting-systems tags"

`election`, `voting`, `president` and `voting-systems` have specific 'tag' markup.

I have attempted to find out what this markup is, but since editing of others' posts is not allowed for people below a certain rep on meta sites (as a general rule) I have been unable to look at the code to see how it is done.

How does one mark a specific section of the body of a meta question as containing a 'tag'?

Comment: You'll use `[tag:tag-name]`

Comment: Awesome. Is this listed in the markup help anywhere? I had a look and didn't see anything...

Comment: Yes, [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help) under "Stack Exchange additions". (Clicking the question mark in the top right of the editor opens a link to "advanced help", leading there)

Comment: Oh yeah. Whoops. Must have skimmed straight over it :/.

Comment: To mark up meta tags, use `[meta-tag:tagName]`.  Also, camelCase is better for combining words without spaces.  Nyah.

Comment: You could also click the `edit` link under the post, and see how they did it.

Comment: @Mat'sMug: You mean the one that's disabled for users under 2k on metas, and the one that will never show tag markdown on main sites because it's disabled there?

Comment: @NathanTuggy *cough* yeah that one.

Comment: @Mat'sMug: (No offense, I trust. ;))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To use the tag markdown, type `[tag:tag-name]`. This will also link to the tag page on the main Q&A.

If you want to link to a *meta* tag, use the markdown `[meta-tag:tag-name]`.

To view the markdown help:

<from the post editor> click `?` → '[advanced help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help)' → **Tags**